# Postfix : How to hold failed sent message instead of reject it

Tags: linux, postfix, squirrelmail

Can i edit the attachments list (add more files, delete selected attachments), after got an error report (`Message not sent. Server replied: Requested mail action aborted: exceeding storage allocation 552 53.4 Error : message file too big`)
 It automatically disappears after the list updated.

- I send the mail with telnet from client pc
- The problem is on the attachment list, not on the error message